# PHP get function's result from class itself?

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to receive the results from a function "from the class itself". An example of this is the PDO functions, where I can do the following to get i.e. the last ID:

```
$db->query($sql);
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Right now I have to do the following:

```
$newThread = $forums->newThread('title','category');
$id = $newThread['id'];
```

Of course this works great, but I have to use the variable $newThread, which I don't want to. How do I save the value in order to call it later?

Comment: Store it as *state* in a class/object property...?!

Comment: The way it works now looks good to me

Comment: Simple return $array['id'] from function newThread itself instead of returning $array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have problems understanding how the PDO version works, it's roughly like this:

```
class PDO {

    private $lastInsertId;

    public function query($sql) {
        magic_sql_api_call($sql);
        /* here be dragons */

        $this->lastInsertId = magic_sql_api_get_last_insert_id();
    }

    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->lastInsertId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create code like this

```
class Forums {
    private $id;
    ...

    function createTread($title, $category) {
       $newThread = $forums->newThread($title, $category);
       $this->id = $newThread['id'];
    }
    function lastId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

You can use it

```
$forums->createTread('title','category');
$id = $forums->lastId();
```

You probably will need to save $newThread in property too.